# Error using a value in a range condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everybody I have a problem trying to use @year like text in a query condition

I used:

```
SET @year := "2013";

SELECT count(*) as July FROM sinisters
WHERE date BETWEEN "@year-07-01" AND "@year-07-31" )
```

And i got nothing.

Also I tried:

```
SET @year := "2013";

SELECT year(date) as July FROM sinisters
WHERE date BETWEEN "'{@year}'-07-01" AND "'{@year}'-07-31" )
```

I want to use @year like 2013.

Please someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to concatenate the variable and the fixed text:

`SELECT count(*) as July 
   FROM sinisters
  WHERE date BETWEEN CONCAT(@year, "-07-01") AND CONCAT(@year, "-07-31")`